# how do you use the --optimize-minimize flag with webpack

Tags: webpack

How should I go about using the --optimize-minimize flag with webpack. What does adding that flag to the command do? Do I still need to add the UglifyJsPlugin to the plugins list in the webpack config if I am using the --optimize-minimize flag? Does it help me decide whether to add it to the list of plugins or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does adding that flag to the command do?

It will reduce your js/CSS files size.

> Do I still need to add the UglifyJsPlugin to the plugins list in the webpack config if I am using the --optimize-minimize flag?

Same effect, so you can choose what you like.

> Does it help me decide whether to add it to the list of plugins or not?

As a suggestion, always use this or use it before putting the code to production(maybe this process will slow down the building process).

Comment: Is there any way to make a configuration that have the same effect as adding this option? I'd like to keep my webpack commands as simple as possible, eg. `webpack --config=webpack.prod.js`. Adding the `--optimize-minimize` flag minimizes the js, css and html files as well and I'd like to do the same without any additional plugins. So the real question is what does webpack do in the background when this flag is specified?